# Smooth line after zooming

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, quartz-core

I am trying to implement a drawing feature. Currently I am using UIBezierPath:

```
@interface DrawView : UIView {
    UIBezierPath *myPath;
}
@end

@implemenation DrawView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    //...normal init code
    myPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
    myPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    myPath.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinRound;
    myPath.miterLimit = 0;
    myPath.lineWidth = 10;
}
```

In `touchesBegan:` I track the startPoint and call `[myPath moveToPoint:myTouch locationInView:self];`
In `touchesMoved:` I call `[myPath addLineToPoint...]; [self setNeedsDisplay]`.

My DrawView is a subview of a UIScrollView.

**My problem**:
When I zoom in the drawing is very cornered or pixelated.

I want to redraw the drawing in a way so it looks nice and smooth, but I can't figure out how or where to start.

I've found this simple "solution":

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView*)scrollView withView:(UIView*)view atScale:(float)scale {
    view.layer.contentsScale = scale;
    [view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

When I implement the method in this way the drawing will be smoother after zomming, but the App becomes really laggy and slow. At a high `maximumZoomScale` of the scrollView the App crahes completely. When I understand the docu correctly setting contentsScale higher than 2 isn't a good idea or changing contensScale in any way isn't so good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem (I'm still facing other problems with drawing...):
When zooming is finished I call a method that looks like this:

```
    -(void)redrawWithScale:(float)scale {
        _myPath.lineWidth = _myPath.lineWidth * scale //currently _myPath is a UIBezierPath, with CGPath it should be equal
        [_myPath applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale)];

        [self setNeedsDisplay];

        //or with a CAShapeLayer:
        _shapeLayer.path = _myPath.CGPath;
   }
```

Edit:

In my current implementation I'm using a `CAShapeLayer` (as a sublayer of my UIView). The UIBezierPath is set to the `path` attribute of the shapeLayer.
Calling `setNeedsDisplay` isn't neccessary with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the WWDC 2012 video [Optimizing 2D Graphics and Animation Performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=506) for some good techniques.  Off-hand I'd advise reducing or eliminating transparent layers and concatenating your individual line segments when possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting this link. It helps to understand quartz core and it't optimizing. I have to play with the optimizing steps from the session video. But I think this will not answer my zooming question. Quite know I found some iOS paint examples, but never with zooming.